# Can't login to MySQL Server externally

Tags: mysql, sql, azure

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server running on Microsoft Azure, and I have a MySQL Server running on that. I have 2 users, root and MattyAB (Me), which I created with this command:

```
GRANT CREATE ON *.* To 'MattyAB'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '********';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'MattyAB'@'localhost';
```

Where * is my password. I then try to connect to the server with my personal computer, but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?
Do I need to change this @'localhost' to something else?

Comment: Have you opened the port that mysql runs on to external access?

Answer (score 1):

So I have ran into this problem with other things that I have done.

So you basically just need to run the following command after identifying what port your mySql runs on.

In Your Ubuntu Terminal. Run This

```
EXPOSE <PORT NO>
```

Try sudo expose if this does not work.

Comment: Oops my bad should have been clearer where to run this. Edited my answer, you need to run this at the ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 0):

What have you done? You gave grants to access all databases and tables `*.*` at your server to the account

> 'MattyAB'@'localhost'.

Localhost obviously is not an extern account. As far as I know you have to use the `'%'` operator instead of `'localhost'`, or just the IP from which you want to log on to your mysql server.

You need something like this: `GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'MattyAB'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '******';` I am not sure with the single quotes around the %. In case of error try both types of syntax.
Furthermore you can take a look at [MYSQL Grant Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).

With `SHOW GRANTS FOR MattyAB` you can check your grants configuration.

Comment: localhost is correct as thats the location of the user he wants to grant the privileges to.

Comment: Yes, but he question was "Can't login to MySQL Server externally" ;) The syntax is read "account at machine". You can vary the grants to the same account depending on the machine at which the account is used to log on the mysql server. Set `@'localhost'` means you have to be at localhost to login to the server, what is like the server is installed at the same machine the user is loggin on with. He wants to log in from extern. And extern is never localhost ;)

Comment: I've done that, and it gives the following: http://pastebin.com/FbDFvPJ2, but I still can't get in from my computer.

Comment: Yes I'm just SSHing into my server, so it will need to be accessible externally

Comment: Did you have correctly import the ssh key to your unix machine? The grants look ordinary.

Comment: hm, the part with your password is missing. SHOW GRANTS should result in something like `GRANT CREATE PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'MattyAB@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '***********'`